# Value of type 'HistoryViewController' has no member 'match'

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot figure out what the error "Value of type 'HistoryViewController' has no member 'match'" is telling me. Directly above, similar code seems to work:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "throwDownScissors" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
            controller.match = self.match
        }

        else if segue.identifier == "showHistory" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! HistoryViewController
            controller.match = self.match
        }
    }
```

Why does the second bit of code trigger the error?

Comment: You are casting to two different types. Do both of them have `match` property specified?

Comment: No, only one has a `match` property specified.

Comment: So there you have - the cause of the error and the answer to your question. The second bot triggers the error, because the type doesn’t have a `match` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your ResultViewController has a match property declared inside it but HistoryViewController doesn't have this property so when the if statment go through the else condition it cannot call the match property which is not existing since you force casted the destination controller to HistoryViewController